# how to ensure an arrayadapter does not accept duplicate values

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

i have a custom arrayadapter with some pre_populated data and more data is to be added to it from  the user input.The problem is that  duplicate values are still added to the arrayadapter..here is my code:

```
String s;//holds data from user input

for(int i=0 ; i<my_adapter.getCount() ; i++){
 MyCollection itemObject=my_adapter.getItem(i);
 //MyCollection is an object from the collection class
 String c=itemObject.toString();

     if(c.matches(s)){
     //do not add s to array adapter

}else{
   //add s to arrayadapter
    my_arrayvalues.add(new MyCollection(s));
    my_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Running the above code,no change is effected on the adapter even when the the values do not match..if i just run the project without including  the above
    duplicate values are added.how can i correct this?

after following the answers i have done as suggested but still the duplicates are being added:
**the updated code**

```
             hs = new HashSet();
             my_arrayvalues.add(new MyCollections(s));
             hs.addAll(my_arrayvalues);
             my_arrayvalues.clear();
             my_arrayvalues.addAll(hs);
             my_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: use equals method instead matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.equals(s)` instead of `String.matches(s)`.

Equals will compare the string objects for equality.

```
String s;//holds data from user input

for(int i=0 ; i<my_adapter.getCount() ; i++){
 MyCollection itemObject=my_adapter.getItem(i);
 //MyCollection is an object from the collection class
 String c=itemObject.toString();

     if(c.equals(s)){
     //do not add s to array adapter

}else{
   //add s to arrayadapter
    my_arrayvalues.add(new MyCollection(s));
    my_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**!!!EDIT!!!**

While the above should fix your problem, I agree with others solution that you should use a `HashSet` instead of checking all elements manually. Using `HashSet` or equivalent will improve performance. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7633852/375093) answer for a better explanation.

Comment: i've done as you suggested but still getting the same problem..i have updated the question,please check it out and assist if you can

Comment: @bloodyshadow your code still shows `matches`. Use `equals` instead. Post the entire code for better results

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Collection that does not allow duplicates. Since you have implemented your custom adapter you can avoid to pass to the super constructor of ArrayAdapter the dataset, and override the methods you need.

For instance you could use a

```
LinkedHashSet
```

and the getCount method should returns the this of the `LinkedHashSet`.  Also, your class could `extend BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`